# Do Remarks in Web References get overwritten?

Tags: c#, web, reference

If I were to add remarks or summaries within a Reference.cs file for a Web Reference would the remarks or summaries get deleted or overwritten at build or run-time?I am asking this because the Reference.cs file in Microsoft Visual Studios 2010 is auto-generated by Microsoft.VSDesigner, so, I'm not sure if it would delete any remarks or summaries I put in. Note: there are,

```
    /// <remarks/>
```

lying around in the Reference.cs file.

When I say summaries or remarks  I mean:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Clears the log file
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender">this instance of the form</param>
    /// <param name="e">Event Arguments</param>
    /// <remarks> Hello </remarks>
    public void mudkip(Object cheese) {...}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you make any changes to the `Reference.cs` file, those changes will be overwritten whenever you update the Web Reference.

It says as much in the comments of the `Reference.cs` file at the top:

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//     This code was generated by a tool.
//     Runtime Version:4.0.30319.296
//
//     Changes to this file may cause incorrect behavior and will be lost if
//     the code is regenerated.
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Yeah, I assumed that, but if that's the case, then why would the auto-generated code be littered with remark tags?

Comment: That's a good question. I couldn't find one instance of the `remarks` tag actually being filled out in any of the `Reference.cs` files in my code. I'm sure that the code generator is used for more than just generating `Reference.cs` files, so maybe one of its other functions make use of the `remarks` tag.

Comment: That was my second guess, but I have no idea where to find it.